# Watertight loft in Sverchok?

Tags: sverchok

[image: Sverchok]

I am trying to loft between two Bezier circles in Sverchok. Using the "Surface from Curves node" that was easy enough, and there are a bunch of tutorials on that.

My question is: how do I close that loft at both ends and make it watertight (e.g. for 3d printing)? I was able to create surfaces for the end caps and tesselate those, but that would not be feasible since the tesselation of the end cap would be disjoint from the loft between the curves.

Here's what I have so far, but that isn't watertight. I think I would have to somehow isolate the vertices for the top circle from the "Surface from Curves" result and grid fill that as in plain Blender.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about using Merge by Distance node or weld modifier?

Comment: @HariSreedhar Hah, thanks! I hadn't realized that Merge by Distance is actually available in Sverchok (Weld isn't, it seems). I will give that a try!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the idea of @HariSreedhar solved it.

Here's my solution: the top row of nodes on the left evaluates the loft, and the bottom two rows create an ngon for each end cap. The nodes on the right-hand side combine everything into one mesh and then merge vertices by distance.

If I bake that, I get one nice watertight object. The advantage over doing something like this in plain Blender is that I can modify the input curves as Beziers, and the mesh will update accordingly.

Thanks again!

[image]